# Rails Naming Convention Issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Hello I have a 1:M relationship between Customer_Status and Customer. Customer_Status applies to many Customers. I put the associations in the corresponding models.

Below is my schema

```
create_table "customer_statuses", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "customer_status_desc"
 t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
end

create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer  "customerstatus_id"
 t.integer  "customertype_id"
 t.string   "first_name"
 t.string   "last_name"
 t.string   "primaryemail"
 t.string   "secondaryemail"
 t.string   "billingcity"
 t.string   "billingstreet"
 t.integer  "billingzip"
 t.integer  "primaryphone"
 t.integer  "secondaryphone"
 t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
end
```

In my Customer Index View I am trying to display attribute `customer_status_desc` from the Customer Status table instead of the `customerstatus_id` found in the Customers table.

In the Customer Index View I have:

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= customer.customer_status.customer_status_desc %></td>
    <td><%= customer.customertype_id %></td>
    <td><%= customer.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= customer.last_name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

For the life of me I cannot get the customer_status_desc to display. I get the error `undefined method customer_status_desc for nil:NilClass` I have tried naming it differently such as `customer.customerstatus.customer_status_desc`

After some research it appears the naming conventions are out of whack. Is there any way to resolve this without changing all of the names. Can I help rails understand what I am trying to call - or possibly force it through a query?

EDIT: 
I am using postgres and rails 4

Customers Controller

```
def index
 @customers = Customer.order(sort_col + " " + sort_dir)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column `customerstatus_id` should be named `customer_status_id`, and be sure that you have a `belongs_to :customer_status` in your `Customer` model.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby conventions

`Class` and `Module` names are CamelCase - `CustomerStatus` never a unholy mix like `Customer_Statuses`.

Other constants are ALL CAPS. This is the only convention the ruby interpreter cares about.

Everything else is snake_case. Attributes, method names, local variables. Snakecase is definiatly preferable to cramming the words together C style.

```
Do               don't

primary_email    primaryemail, primaryEmail
```

Again the Ruby interpreter does not care but your fellow programmers do. The Ruby ecosystem is actually wonderfully consistent. Don't be *that guy*.

## Rails conventions

In rails foreign keys by default are the relation name + `_id`.

So if your model `belongs_to :customer_status`. The column should be named `customer_status_id`.

Active Record has some very specific conventions for how it maps class names to models.

Tables should be plural and models singular:

```
animals -> Animal
```

Compound words are somewhat special case as rails will treat the first word(s) as a namespace if it is plural.

```
user_hobbies -> UserHobby
users_hobbies -> Users::Hobbies
```

Join tables are somewhat special.

In `has_and_belongs_to_many` both are plural:

```
hobbies_users
```

For `has_many through:` the same rules as a normal table as rails actually loads a model:

```
hobby_users HobbyUser
```

Comment: Great thorough answer!  Note: Rails maps model names to table names, not the other way around.  Therefore, if you have a table named `users_hobbies`, that can actually be used for _either_ a model named `UsersHobby` _or_ a model named `Users::Hobby`.

Comment: Also Rails actually maps both ways - sometimes it will fail the constant lookup when loading an association from the database unless it can properly derived from the table name or you use the `class_name` option when declaring the relationship.

Comment: in that case, it's mapping from the association name, not the table name.  Rails looks at the association name to derive the class name, and then looks at the class to derive the table name. I don't think there is ever a case where Rails maps from a table name to a class name.